# How to access guild and members in client.on('ready') event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    
    arrayID = ['DISCORD_ID'];

    guild.members.fetch(arrayID[0]).then(member => {
        return guild.roles.fetch('ROLE_ID');
      }).then(role => {
        return member.roles.add(role);
      }).catch((err) => {
      });

});
```

With that code I am receiving the error: *guild is not defined*
because of that I tried it with

```
client.guild.members.fetch(arrayID[0]).then(member => {
```

But then I am receiving the error: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't defined your `guild` variable, that's why you received the error *"guild is not defined"*. The other one is because `client` doesn't have a `guild` property.

Don't forget that your bot can be in different `guild`s. You can get these guilds using [`client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). It returns a `GuildManager` and its `cache` returns a collection.

If you know your guild ID, you can get the guild like this:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('YOUR_GUILD_ID')
```

If your bot is only in a single guild, you could grab the [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) one in this collection:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.first()
```

Once `guild` is defined, the rest of your code should work, although you should log the error in your `catch` block. Oh, and `member` won't be available in your second `then`, so you should fix that too.

You could use async/await to make it more readable:

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  let arrayID = ['DISCORD_ID'];
  let roleID = '928938568624263178';
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID');

  try {
    let member = await guild.members.fetch(arrayID[0]);
    let role = await guild.roles.fetch(roleID);

    if (!member) return console.log(`Can't find member with ID "${arrayID[0]}"`);
    if (!role) return console.log(`Can't find role with ID "${roleID}"`);

    member.roles.add(role);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! The guild line fixed it. Now no errors. 

But how can i access ´member´ for the second ´then´? 
I tried this: 
``` 
client.on('ready', () => {
    
    arrayID = ['DISCORD_ID'];
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID');

    guild.members.fetch(arrayID[0]).then(member => {
        return guild.roles.fetch('928938568624263178');
      }.then(role => {
        return member.roles.add(role);
      })).catch((err) => {
      });

});
```
Now the bot is marking .then red

Comment: I've just updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! It worked now. Appreciate it!!
Funny point: The console log doesnt work. Error: DiscordAPIError Unknown User. I guess the code will be ended before it can access the if return "cant find member"?